# mysql: Show limited records in mysql shell?

Tags: mysql

When I run this

```
mysql > show tables;
```

It lists all tables, I cant see the first one.

How do I limit the entries like we have `less` in Linux?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a pager in the mysql client.

```
mysql> pager less
mysql> show tables;
. . .
mysql> nopager
```

You can actually set `pager` to any shell command you could normally use in a pipeline.
For example, *grep*.

See some other tips here:  http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/01/21/fun-with-the-mysql-pager-command/

Comment: Cool - this is my fantastic takeaway of the day from Stack Overflow! Obviously explains your 134k reputation! :)

Comment: Thank you. I spent two hours on Google and you/StackOverFlow done it in five minutes :)